# A limit question regarding continuous $f(x)$

Tags: limits

Let $f:\Bbb{R}\mapsto\Bbb{R}$ be a positive increasing function with the following condition:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(3x)}{f(x)}=1$$.

Then what is the value of the following limit?

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(2x)}{f(x)}$$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: since $f$ is increasing and positive, we have that for all $x>0$ $$1 < \frac{f(2x)}{f(x)} < \frac{f(3x)}{f(x)}$$

Comment: I think it should be $\leq$ instead of $\lt$. Otherwise, there is no solution for the problem. Also, isn't this squeeze theorem that you used? If so, you should explicitly mention it in your solution.

Comment: The question states that the function is strictly increasing, so the bounds are strict. And you're incorrect to say that there is no solution for the problem if the bounds are strict. Remember that it is possible that $g(x)<h(x)$ for all $x$, but $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} h(x)$.

Comment: Very good solution (+1) and I am glad that you commented on effect of limits on inequalities. Many students are not fully aware that taking limits weakens the inequalities.